# Help with おうおういっちょ前におったてて because I can't understand!

Tags: meaning, phrases

I'm reading a manga in Japanese and need help with this, because I can't understand what it really means. Thanks!

"おうおういっちょ前におったてて"

Comment: Perhaps you could supplement some sentences before and after. It might be useful to understand the context it is in.

Comment: @Flaw A man was looking for a boy and when he found it, he said that. And sorry, I'm new here by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「おうおういっちょ[前]{まえ}におったてて。」

＝

> 「おうおう、[一丁前]{いっちょうまえ}におっ[立]{た}てて。」

「いっちょ前」 is how we colloquially pronounce 「一丁前」, which means the same thing as 「[一人前]{いちにんまえ}」 = "***a full-fledged man***", "***an adult***", etc.

「おっ」 is a slangy verb prefix that emphasizes the meaning of that verb.

「立てる」 here means "***to get or keep an erection***".

Put it all together, you will have:

> "OMG, you've got a good hard-on like a grown man!"

Other verbs we often use with this prefix include:

おっぱじまる、おっぴらく、おっぴろげる、おったまげる, etc.

Notice the [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) (***'h' ⇒ 'p'***) in the first three above.  You ***must*** use the 'p' sound for those.